# Knockout JS: Calculating average returns NaN?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

#### Background:

I'm building my first web-app, a gradebook. I'm trying to calculate the average score from an observable array of `scores`. The average, called `mean` is an observable object. Both `mean` and `scores` belong to the model.

I'm just not sure what the problem here is. I noticed while printing `mean` to the console that the value printed is NaN OR a code block. My script as well as the console logs can be seen here:

http://jsbin.com/fehoq/20/edit

I'm wondering if adding a number to an observable isn't as straightforward as I'm assuming, but I'm not sure what the correct method would be instead.

Comment: Being an observable, `this.mean` is a function, not a variable. Have a look at the documentaton: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with observables and observable arrays, make sure you read and write to them properly...

In this block of code...

```
this.scores = ko.observableArray([79, 89]);
this.mean = ko.observable();

// ...

ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.scores(), function (score) {
    _this.mean += score;
    console.log(score);
    console.log(_this.mean);
});
_this.mean = _this.mean / _this.scores.length;
console.log(_this.mean);
return _this.mean;
```

`_this.mean += score` overwrites the original observable. Instead it should be `_this.mean(_this.mean() + score)`. This happens in a couple of place.

Same goes for accessing the `scores` observable array. `_this.scores.length` should be `_this.scores().length`.

Here is the code with the changes applied...

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.scores(), function (score) {
     _this.mean(_this.mean() + score);
     console.log(score);
     console.log(_this.mean());
});
_this.mean(_this.mean() / _this.scores().length);
console.log(_this.mean());
return _this.mean();
```

Comment: I'm getting numbers now, perfect. Thanks! I will note that observables are functions.

Comment: Great! Here is a couple more things I've noticed... It's not necessary to have `mean` and `getAvgScore()` (in fact, it might not even work). Just make `mean` a computed (using much of what you have for `getAvgScore()`). Also, the `scores` array should probably contain observables rather than plain numbers if you want the means to change when you change the scores.

Comment: Those are good ideas, I will take some time to implement both changes.

Comment: Actually, let me follow up briefly to your suggestion...what's the best way to make each `score` in `scores` an observable?

Comment: Make sure all values you add to it are observables... For example: `ko.observableArray([ko.observable(79), ko.observable(89)])`